# Show popup on application start only

Tags: android, popup, android-activity

I want to show a pop every time the application starts. The pop should not appear again on moving from another to previous activity. But the pop up must appear again every time the application starts.

This is what i am already using but everytime the application starts first run is set to false.

```
public static firstrun;
firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(
            "firstrun", true);
 if (firstrun) {
            //show popup.
            // Save the state
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    .putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
```

Comment: hey brother r u using the splash screen or not

Comment: yes i am using splash screen

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

YOu can pass the string using bundle putextra method from the splash screen then check it on your main activity if(getIntent.getextra.containsKey("string which is passed by splash screen")) then show the Pop up other wise normal behaviour of application.

Comment: This is what i am doing already.. my splash screen doesn't appear if the remember credentials is checked. popup gets displayed on my home screen from another activity. so in a way or other i am doing exactly the same you mentioned above.. BUT this doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

It's set to false because first of all you need to set `True` value whenever your app is closed . I think that maybe the problem